# My streamreader only reading one line at a time

Tags: c#, asp.net, streamreader

```
string UploadFile = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/");
UploadFile += FileUpload1.FileName;`
try
{
    if (File.Exists(UploadFile))
    {
        File.Delete(FileUpload1.FileName);
    }
    else
    {
        FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(UploadFile);
    }
}
```

This is where it goes wrong in this Finally where my While loop is located..

```
finally
{
    string InputLine, tempSTR, productname, strQuantity, strUnitprice;
    StreamReader ReadFile = new StreamReader(UploadFile);

    while (!ReadFile.EndOfStream)
    { 

        InputLine = ReadFile.ReadLine();

        tempSTR = InputLine.Substring(0, InputLine.IndexOf(","));
        productname = tempSTR;
        InputLine = InputLine.Substring(InputLine.IndexOf(",") + 1).Trim();

        tempSTR = InputLine.Substring(0, InputLine.IndexOf(","));
        strQuantity = tempSTR;
        InputLine = InputLine.Substring(InputLine.IndexOf(",") +1).Trim();

        strUnitprice = InputLine;

        b.NAME = productname;
        b.QUANTITY = int.Parse(strQuantity);
        b.UNITPRICE = int.Parse(strUnitprice);
        b.AddProducts();
    }

    GridView1.DataSource = b.ViewProducts();
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

In my while loop there's is the error when I try to upload several lines like:

Acer P166HQL LED Monitor,    97, 2999 
   Acer S200HQL LED Monitor,    50, 4499 
   DELL UltraSharp 2005FPW LCD Monitor, 22, 29999 
   Gateway KX1563 LED Monitor,  66, 2988

Comment: "there is the error" - what error?

Comment: It says "Length cannot be less than zero. Parameter name: length" when I tried to upload the text file that contains the following lines:

Acer P166HQL LED Monitor,97,2999
ASRock Penryn 1600SLi,42,4688
Gateway KX1563 LED Monitor,66,2988

But when I re-run the program the last uploaded lines shows on the gridview but when I will upload it for the first time that error always pop out.. So i need to re-run always the program to see the recently uploaded files..

Comment: Use a [Csv parser](http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) to parse comma separated files.

Comment: Is there a separate way to do it?

Comment: The program can only read one line at a time. It cannot read many lines like when you upload multiple lines in one text file..

Comment: This has nothing to do with reading from the stream if the error is not in the part where you are reading. Your error is with parsing CSV. Use the debugger. You *must* have the skill to use a debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know your file structure, but i think if you using parse this way, you haven't problem anymore :

```
finally
{

    string InputLine, tempSTR, productname, strQuantity, strUnitprice;
    StreamReader ReadFile = new StreamReader(UploadFile);
    string fileContent = ReadFile.ReadToEnd();
    fileContent = fileContent.Replace("\r\n",",");
    string[] splitedText = fileContent .Split(',');
    int j = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i < splitedText.Length ; i++)
    {
      switch(j)
      {
         case 0:
          j++;
          b.NAME = splitedText[i];
         break;
         case 1:
          j++;
          b.QUANTITY = int.Parse(splitedText[i]);
         break;
         case 2:
          j=0;
          b.UNITPRICE = int.Parse(splitedText[i]);
          b.AddProducts();
         break;
      }
    }
    GridView1.DataSource = b.ViewProducts();
    GridView1.DataBind();

}
```

**UPDATE**

I change the entire code based on your comments :

```
  string s = @" Acer P166HQL LED Monitor, 97, 2999 ASRock Penryn 1600SLi, 42, 4688 Gateway KX1563 LED Monitor, 66, 2988";
            string[] splitedText = s.Split(' ');
            StringBuilder sr = new StringBuilder();
            int countOfCommas = 0;
            bool needComma = false;
            foreach (string item in splitedText)
            {
                if (needComma)
                {
                    needComma = false;
                    sr.Append(item).Append(',').Append(' ');
                }
                else if (item.Contains(","))
                {
                    if (countOfCommas == 1)
                    {
                        countOfCommas = 0;
                        needComma = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        countOfCommas++;
                    }
                    sr.Append(item).Append(' ');
                }
                else
                {
                    sr.Append(item).Append(' ');
                }
            }

            string str = sr.ToString();
            string[] splitedTextByComma = str.Split(',');
            int j = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < splitedTextByComma.Length; i++)
            {
                switch (j)
                {
                    case 0:
                        j++;
                        string NAME = splitedTextByComma[i];
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        j++;
                        int QUANTITY = int.Parse(splitedTextByComma[i]);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        j = 0;
                        int UNITPRICE = int.Parse(splitedTextByComma[i]);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

the `s` variable has some values that your said.i hope this helps.

Comment: b.UNITPRICE = int.Parse(splitedText[i]); has some error it says "Input string was not in a correct format" when I try multiple lines to upload but i also tried one line to upload and it works.. I wonder how can it upload multiple lines..?

Comment: @JmSantos please put your some lines of your file, maybe it's help us to know

Comment: That's the only button that i have codes.. Just the upload button..

Comment: @JmSantos I mean your file's content, not your source code.the content exactly you got error

Comment: These content? these are the lines i need to be uploaded in one upload session

>Acer P166HQL LED Monitor, 97, 2999
>Acer S200HQL LED Monitor, 50, 4499
>DELL UltraSharp 2005FPW LCD Monitor 22, 29999
>Gateway KX1563 LED Monitor, 66, 2988
>HP W1972A LCD Monitor, 93, 4199
>HP Pavilion 23TM Touch Monitor, 81, 18990
>Lenovo LI1921WA Wide LED TFT Monitor, 83, 4788,

Comment: @JmSantos see the update, i think your file is wrong structure somewhere.

Comment: I can upload multiple lines with same lines with each other like 3 lines with "DELL UltraSharp 2005FPW LCD Monitor, 22, 29999" but when I upload different 3 lines with correct commas it's not working.

Comment: @JmSantos Updatet the answer by : fileContent.Replace("\r\n",",");
 Please test it again.

Comment: In the "b.QUANTITY = int.Parse(splitedText[i]);" it says input string was not in a correct format. The lines i wish to upload are these lines... 

Acer P166HQL LED Monitor, 97, 2999
ASRock Penryn 1600SLi, 42, 4688
Gateway KX1563 LED Monitor, 66, 2988

Comment: @JmSantos See the updated answer, it should be work.